# Incomingcall notification is not displayed in android wear device

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

i am using android wear emulator with real device which is already  connected.Android wear displayed my message notification but i can not receive any notification when i receive incoming call...

So basically how receive incoming calls with notification in Android wear?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/g-watch-r/help/incoming-call-notification-t3105321). If you are using LG wear, suggested solution is to go to your `Watch settings` -> `Bluetooth` -> `Play phone audio on watch` (OFF by default on LG Urbane 2nd ed). You may also check this [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-watch-urbane/675369-no-incoming-call-notification.html) which recommended to make sure that you have enabled all the permissions in your Android wear.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the Android Wear app (or Wear OS as it's called as off today) on your phone doesn't have the right permissions.

You can fix this by going to your phone's `settings > applications > Android Wear/Wear OS > Permissions`. Over there, enable the `phone` permission. You might also want to enable the `contacts` permissions to let your phone display contact information.